# How to handle ProvisionedThroughputExceededException error without increasing read/write capacity in node.js

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless, amazon-dynamodb

When I create a bulk of data, `dynamodb` raises a `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` error. I did not want to change the capacity. How can I handle this in node.js

```
2021-09-30T07:01:05.608Z    9ec62d61-f9c5-4bd1-8853-fb6466f269cd    INFO    ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: The level of configured provisioned throughput for one or more global secondary indexes of the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level for the under-provisioned global secondary indexes with the UpdateTable API
    at Request.extractError (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/task/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'ProvisionedThroughputExceededException',
  time: 2021-09-30T07:01:05.605Z,
  requestId: '9KVC4C9JUSB400051MGBMIF6URVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: true
}
```

Comment: Only the provisioned mode is covered by the free tier.  Is there an option to get it to actually throttle properly instead of erroring?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do so is not to define the provisioned capacity at all. Instead what you can do is, use:

```
BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
```

Using PAY_PER_REQUEST billing mode means you are on pay as you go pricing plan. Here are some useful links [[1]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html) [[2]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html#HowItWorks.OnDemand) that can give you more insight.

Answer (score -1):

The error message you see specifically notes that it's one or more secondary indexes that do not have sufficient throughput provisioned. The following can be read from [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html#GSI.ThroughputConsiderations):

> To avoid potential throttling, the provisioned write capacity for a global secondary index should be equal or greater than the write capacity of the base table because new updates write to both the base table and global secondary index.

Basically, if you don't want to increase the write capacity units on your GSI, you should only write as much data to the table as the lowest provisioned GSI can handle.

Comment: can i increase gsi dynamically in node.js,

Comment: You can either use provisioned throughput (which you pay for) or you can use pay-per-request which will dynamically scale up and down the throughput depending on usage. You could also dynamically set the provisioned throughput using a call with the aws-sdk, but I'm not sure that's really advisable.

Comment: This is not a throttle, it is an error.  There shouldn't be any reason to manually do the throttling to avoid getting the error.